# CodenameOne Image Slider using Image Viewer

Tags: codenameone

Is it possible to achieve something similar to the attachment using imageviewer. I already have images loaded using the DefaultListModel but I would like something similar to the screenshot where part of the next image shows so the user knows there is a next image and if possible the slider at the bottom of the screen.

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the people who did that used the `Tabs` widget which is more suitable for that sort of usage. You can see some discussion of this here:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/codenameone-discussions/06hLjMkia-4/4oi4wBaMKe0J